# form is undefined after being submitted (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Please help me with this. I want to store username in a cookie after user successfully login. But after login button clicked, the form is of undefined and I cannot use `addEventListener` property from it. As the result, the cookie is not created. Chrome browser gives me an error in `if` condition about `loginForm` is undefined (in `createEventListener()` function prototype).

index.htm

```
<form action="results.htm">
    <fieldset id="deliveryinfo">
        <legend>Site Login</legend>
        <label for="usernameinput">Username</label>
        <input type="text" id="usernameinput" name="username" />
        <label for="passwordinput">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="passwordinput" name="password" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="submitbutton">
        <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" value="Login" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

scripts.js

```
"use strict";

function processCookie() {
    document.cookie = "username=" +document.getElementById('usernameinput').value;
}

function populateInfo() {
    if (document.cookie) {
        var uname = document.cookie;
        uname = uname.substring(uname.lastIndexOf("=") + 1);
        document.getElementById('usernameinput').value = uname;
    }
}

function handleSubmit(evt) {
    if (evt.preventDefault) {
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
    else {
        evt.returnValue = false;
    }
    processCookie();
    document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].submit();
}

function createEventListener() {
    var loginForm = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
    if (loginForm.addEventListener) {
        loginForm.addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit, false);
    }
    else if (loginForm.attachEvent) {
        loginForm.attachEvent("onsubmit", handleSubmit);
    }
}

function setUpPage() {
    populateInfo();
    createEventListener();
}

if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("load", setUpPage, false);
}
else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent("onload", setUpPage);
}
```

Comment: Theres no sense in clientside authentification. And the page stops existing after a submit, no js will be run at all

Comment: You are right, in real-life website, the entered username and password would be submitted to a web server for verification (I'm not there yet :)).
I'm just getting used to common use of cookies on a site that requires logging in to save a user’s login name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set expires date. If you don't set expires cookie is session bound & when you leave page (submit) it is destroyed. Adding "path=/" also makes cookie available on all site pages.

```
function processCookie() {
    //cookie lifetime in milliseconds (24 hours)
    var date = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 3600 * 1000); 
    document.cookie = "username=" +document.getElementById('usernameinput').value+"; path=/; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
}
```

Comment: I'll get to set expires date in the next step but right now I need to have username field populated with the username stored in a cookie after user reloaded or refreshed the page.